# Understand recursion of w3.includeHTML JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, innerhtml

The below JavaScript function includes HTML from a file within an HTML tag with class "w3-include-html."

Can someone explain why w3.includeHTML(cb), so the function itself, is called again in the middle of the function? Doesn't that generate an infinite loop? Any help much appreciated.

```
w3.includeHTML = function(cb) {
  var z, i, elmnt, file, xhttp;
  z = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
  for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
    elmnt = z[i];
    file = elmnt.getAttribute("w3-include-html");
    if (file) {
      xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          elmnt.innerHTML = this.responseText;
          elmnt.removeAttribute("w3-include-html");
          w3.includeHTML(cb);
        }
      }      
      xhttp.open("GET", file, true);
      xhttp.send();
      return;
    }
  }
  if (cb) cb();
};
```

Comment: This is just a recursive call - so that if in the content you just loaded and inserted into the document there are again element with this attribute, the same operation gets performed on them as well. It will not create an infinite loop, because the function will not be called again, if no further elements with that attribute exist.

Comment: It is a rather bad solution nevertheless (yes, w3schools is reliable in that regard), because it loops over every single element in the document each time. Selecting only the elements that have the attribute set in the first place would make more sense, and is possible even in vanilla JS using document.querySelectorAll these days.

Comment: No. It's not an infinite loop, because it removes the attribute from the page, then runs the function again retrieves all the attributes that are there and tries to iterate it, which it won't as it just removed it, unless the page you just loaded contains the attributes, then the function will run again, but targeting attributes on freshly loaded page. As pointed above, it's called a recursive call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can someone explain why w3.includeHTML(cb), so the function itself, is called again in the middle of the function?

In cause the file you included tries to include something else.

> Doesn't that generate an infinite loop?

No, because the previous line removed the attribute from the element that has done the include.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. Can you maybe say what the line `if (cb) cb();` does at the end? This is the only other thing that's still not clear to me.

Comment: It calls the callback function if you passed one.